Why I don't have the sub-menu for Azure Monitor Logs in API Management?
I'm trying to inspect Azure OpenAI requests and responses logs. As explained in the official Azure blog post "Implement logging and monitoring for Azure OpenAI models", Azure OpenAI doesn't store requests and responses logs by default, so one has to set up Azure API Management backend in order to store such logs and be able to view them.
I found a decent video walkthrough (Log & Monitor Everything in Azure Open AI with API Management Service), which I followed closely, but there's a certain step I got stuck at:
Question: In the API Management service, why I don't have the "Logs" sub-menu under the "Monitoring" menu?
Here's a comparison of the API Management service's menu the video tutorial displays vs. what I see:


The end goal is to be able to use the API's Logs for ApiManagementGatewayLogs, as shown in the video:



This is because I was under the Consumption tier, and as explained in an another tutorial (Tutorial: Monitor published APIs), this is not possible:


Note: A Consumption tier instance can't be changed to another tier, as answered here: Unable to change pricing tier for API Management currently in Consumption tier

